# Postgresql application server cannot be started

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-10

After Installing Postgresql, when I open pgadmin 4, It shows **" The application server cannot be started"** error.
I tried all ways by reinstalling postgresql and delete the pgadmin folder from appdata\Roaming.
Even I cant restart the service, It automatically stop once I started and stop the service from task manager also and  also changes the port number. Its not working.. I am struck.. Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried running as Administrator? Also sometimes windows firewall blocks the localhost port.

Comment: I uninstall completely and also I deleted the registry value and pgadmin folder. Now it's working fine. Thanks for your help :).